# Como puedo convertir una variable de tipo string a un date y time en php

Tags: php, sql-server, json, pdo

### Tengo una duda lo que quiero es insertar dos variables las cuales las tengo de tipo string y en mi base de datos una la tengo como DATE y la otra como TIME (para poder hacer una resta despues)

por ejemplo:

v1 = 26/03/2022 (string)

v2 = 12:30:20 (string)

lo que estoy intentado por ahora es tratar de convertir la v1 de tipo string a date y guardarla y creo que con la v2 seria algo parecido, Pero no logro hacerlo ya que me sigue siendo un string cuando hago un ehco del tipo de dato

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);

$Hora = $data["Hora"];
$Dia = $data["Dia"];
$mes = $data["meses"];
$año = $data["Año"];
$DatosF = $Dia ."-". $mes ."-". $año;
echo $DatosF;
$Fecha= date("d/m/Y", strtotime($DatosF));
echo $Fecha;

//imprimo que tipo de dato es y sigue siendo un string 

echo gettype($Fecha);

$Registro = $cnn->prepare("INSERT INTO Tbla( FechaE, HoraE) VALUES ( ?, ?)");
$Registro ->bindparam(1, $Fecha);
$Registro ->bindparam(2, $Hora);
$Registro ->execute();
```

Comment: [Este enlace](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-converting-string-to-date-and-datetime/) debería servirte...

Comment: intente algo así pero ni me funciono

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la base de datos tiene la columna tipos **DATE** le tienes que enviar los valores como `yyyy-mm-dd`, aunque en el visualizador lo puedan mostrar de muchos formatos.

Para alimentar una base de datos, le tienes que enviar la información como **string** (formateado correctamente), **entero** o **null**. Si usas consultas preparadas el sistema se encarga de hacer las conversiones de `string` -> `al tipo respectivo`.

Entonces eso es lo que le tienes que enviar:

```
// ... 
$Hora = $data["Hora"]; // H:i:s
$DatosF = $data["Año"] . '-' . $data["meses"] . '-' . $data["Dia"]; // Y-m-d

$Registro = $cnn->prepare("INSERT INTO Tbla(FechaE, HoraE) VALUES (?, ?)");
$Registro ->bindparam(1, $DatosF);
$Registro ->bindparam(2, $Hora);
$Registro ->execute();
// ...
```

Comment: HOOO gracias.
y si quisiera guardarlo en el formato d/m/y se podria?
 y si la variable hora aun que la tenga en time si puedo hacer una resta con un nuevo dato igual de tipo time?

Comment: @Francisco No es recomendable guardar fechas en formato diferente a Y-m-d porque las comparaciones no se pueden hacer de forma natural. Por ejemplo: `'03/04/2022' > '26/03/2022'`, da `false` (erróneo), pero si se hace como `'2022-04-03' > '2022-03-26'` da `true` (correcto). Internamente SIEMPRE trabaja con ese formato de fecha y la hora tipo 24 horas. Luego para presentárselo al usuario puedes hacer las conversiones correspondientes.

Comment: hooo ok.
pues es que así lo quieren por eso preguntaba

Comment: @Francisco Si la columna es DATE, como expliqué, se maneja internamente ese tipo de dato y el Management Studio (por ejemplo) te puede mostrar la fecha de muchas maneras, pero internamente es DATE. Si quieres guardar una fecha en otro formato la columna tendrás que especificarla como VARCHAR. Esto, desde ya te lo digo: es **MALA IDEA** y un **error de diseño**. Al hacer consultas la BD te va a arrojar valores erróneos porque estás rompiendo la lógica natural del incremento y comparación de fechas. Solucionarlo será más tortuoso que diseñar correctamente la BD.